# Problem with .env file being read in javascript project

Tags: javascript, npm, environment-variables, dotenv

I am using a .env file to store API Key. However, I can't seem to get to get my base JavaScript file to read the .env file. I have installed the dotenv npm package but it does not appear to be working and I am not sure what is going on.

I have made sure my .env is in the root of my project. See the picture below:

[image]

I have also installed the latest version of dotenv.

This is the code in the fixer-service.js that is trying to access the .env file:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const axios = require("axios");

const symbols = process.env.SYMBOLS || "EUR,USD,GBP";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://data.fixer.io/api",
  params: {
    access_key: process.env.API_KEY
  },
  timeout: process.env.TIMEOUT || 5000
});
```

And this is the code in server.js that is trying to access the .env file:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const { getRates } = require("./lib/fixer-service");

// read .env files

const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

And this is the code in the .env file (I have removed the API-Key):

```js
API_KEY=api-key
PORT=3000
TIMEOUT=5000
SYMBOLS=EUR,USD,GBP,AUD,BTC,KES,JPY,CNY
```

When I tried to run my development server I get this error message:

> ````
> (node:9045) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: missing_access_key
>     at get (/Users/selina/Desktop/single-page-application/lib/fixer-service.js:22:9)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
> (node:9045) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
>     This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>     function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>     not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)```
> ````

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full path to your `.env` file and seeing if that works? `require('dotenv').config({ path: full/path/here })` - I'd suggest using something like `path.join(__dirname, '...')` for getting the full path

Comment: Yes I have tried specifying the full path it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you update your question with your project/folder structure and your `.env` file (without exposing the `API_KEY` of course

Comment: And this code is inside `server.js` and you're running your code by doing `node server.js`?

Comment: I have updated my question with more information.

Comment: Its borking and not setting it, there is an example in docs for debugging whats being loaded, https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#config - and check the file is saved as unix, not dos ie LF not CR\LF

Comment: dotenv will return an error if it can't find your .env file or has something else go wrong. turning on `debug` will also show you line-by-line detail of what's going on. `const { error } = require('dotenv').config({ debug: true }); console.error(error)`

Comment: @SelinaBeasley I can't get it to reproduce with the code that you've given, unless there's something missing... It seems like the error you're getting is due to some other issue that's not included with your current code; you're using the `api` by calling it inside of `getRates`, so maybe there's something wrong there... But this setup should work - https://imgur.com/a/Ddzu2oV. Also, you don't have to do `require('dotenv').config()` everywhere you're trying to read `process.env` variables. Just do it once in your entry file - in your case it's the `server.js` file (see my example)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, but don't have a great explanation as to why it works! Would appreciate if anyone else weighed in to explain.

Moving the params from `axios.create()` to `api.get()` works:

```js
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://data.fixer.io/api/',
  timeout: process.env.TIMEOUT || 5000
});

const get = async url => {
  const response = await api.get(url, {
    params: { access_key: process.env.API_KEY }
  });
  const { data } = response;
  if (data.success) {
    return data;
  }
  throw new Error(data.error.type);
};
```